# Which HTML5 tag should I wrap Rails flash notices in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

Is there a 'best' HTML5 element to use for Rails flash notices?
I'm currently using a `<section>` tag but if there's something that is somehow better for SEO (minor concern), or more cross-browser friendly (major concern), I'd prefer to do it that way.

Thanks.

Comment: Edited to reflect that my actual concern is more to do with cross-browser rendering than SEO. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

If search engines are seeing your flash messages at all, you might be doing something wrong.  Flash messages are (usually) used to give the user some feedback after they do something that changes something in the system.  Like "the record has been saved" type of thing.  Search engines shouldn't be doing write operations, so shouldn't need to see flash messages.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Thanks. I was also generally concerned about cross-browser issues. I had a `section` with nested `section` class = .container that FireFox missed (changed the later to a `div` and it worked fine). In retrospect, I think I was primarily worried about those types of issues.